# HTML body tag appears blank in the browser while it is not empty

Tags: javascript, html

Please help!

My html body tag appears blank in the browser console while it's not empty. This is happening after I added some javascript tags in the head of my html. It is behaving strange as when I remove all the javascript tags from the head of my html and run my html page in the browser, the javascript code (now removed from the html) appears inside the body tag while it's not even in the entire html. I'm getting frustrated now. Look at my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd"> 
<html lang="en"> 
<head> 
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"> 
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="res/styles/w3.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="res/fonts/icomoon/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="res/styles/searchform.css">

        <link href="res/styles/easy-autocomplete.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <link href="res/styles/easy-autocomplete.themes.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <script src="res/js/jquery.easy-autocomplete.min.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>

        <link href="res/styles/floats.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <link href="res/styles/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <script src="res/js/getMedia.js" type="text/javascript"></script>           
    <script src="res/js/jsQR.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

    // hide #back-top first
    $("#go-to-top").hide();

    // fade in #back-top
    $(function () {
        $(window).scroll(function () {
            if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
                $('#go-to-top').fadeIn();
            } else {
                $('#go-to-top').fadeOut();
            }
        });

        // scroll body to 0px on click
        $('#go-to-top').click(function () {
            $('#content-base').animate({
                scrollTop: 0
            }, 800);
            return false;
        });
    });

}); 
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var client;
var camStream;
var QRtarget;
function w3_open() {
    document.getElementById("nav-menu").style.width = "100%";
    document.getElementById("nav-menu").style.opacity = "0.8";
}
function w3_close() {
    document.getElementById("nav-menu").style.width = "0";
    document.getElementById("nav-menu").style.opacity = "0";
}
function w3_open_cart() {
    document.getElementById("nav-cart").style.width = "100%";
    document.getElementById("nav-cart").style.opacity = "0.85";
}
function w3_close_cart() {
    document.getElementById("nav-cart").style.width = "0";
    document.getElementById("nav-cart").style.opacity = "0";
}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function showDialog(wbtn){
    switch(wbtn){
        case 1:
            $('#div-dialog-cover').fadeIn();
            $('#div-dialog-back').slideDown();
            trackNum();
            dialogCmd = 'tracknum';
            break;
        case 2:
        break;
        case 3:
        break;
        case 4:
            $('#div-dialog-cover').fadeIn();
            $('#div-dialog-back').slideDown();
            genQR();
            dialogCmd = 'genqr';
        break;
        case 5:         
            $('#div-dialog-cover').fadeIn();
            $('#div-dialog-back').slideDown();
            scanQR();
            dialogCmd = 'scanqr';
        break;
        case 6:
            $('#div-dialog-cover').fadeIn();
            $('#div-dialog-back').slideDown();
            loginForm();            
            dialogCmd = 'login';
    }
}
function QRfound(QRdata){
    setTimeout(function() {
        closeDialog(QRdata);  // You used `el`, not `element`?
    }, 1000);
}
function closeDialog(QRdata = ''){
    if (dialogCmd == 'genqr'){

    } else if (dialogCmd == 'scanqr') {
        $('#scanning').hide();
        camStream.getTracks().forEach(track => track.stop());
        if (QRdata){
            alert(QRdata);
        }
        readingQR = 0;
        $('#canvas').hide();
    }
    $('#dialog-content').html('');
    $('#div-dialog-cover').fadeOut();
    $('#div-dialog-back').slideUp();
}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var dialogCmd;
function initVars(){
    client = "c";
}
function trackNum(){
    document.getElementById('dialog-label').innerHTML = 'Enter tracking number';
    $('#div-tracker').css('margin-top', '20px');
    $('#dialog-label').css('font-size', '0.8em');
    $('#div-dialog-body').css('max-height', '300px');
    $('#dialog-content').html('<div id="div-tracker"><form id="form-tracker"><label for="tracking-num">Enter tracking Number:</label><input id="tracking-input" type="text" name="tracking-num" /><br><br><button id="submit-track" onclick="submitTrack()">Track now!</button><br><br><div>OR</div><br><button id="btn-QR-track" onclick="trackQR()">Scan a QR to track</button></form></div>');
}
function scanQR(){
    document.getElementById('dialog-label').innerHTML = 'Aim at a QR';
    $('#div-dialog-body').css('max-height', '350px');
    $('#dialog-content').html('<div id="reader"><div id="scanning"></div><canvas id="canvas" style="width:266px" hidden></canvas></div>');
    getCamReady();
}
function genQR(){
    $('#dialog-label').css('font-size', '0.7em');   
    $('#dialog-label').css('padding', '0 2px'); 
    document.getElementById('dialog-label').innerHTML = 'Click to regenerate';
    $('#div-dialog-body').css('max-height', '350px');
    $('#dialog-content').html('<div id="qrview" onclick="regenQR()"></div>');   
    if (QRtarget == 1){
        $('#qrview').css('background', 'url(<?php require('api/getqr.php?t=1') ?>) no-repeat center center');
    } else if (QRtarget == 2){
        $('#qrview').css('background', 'url(<?php require('api/getqr.php?t=2') ?>) no-repeat center center');       
    }
    $('#qrview').css('background-size', '100%');
}
function regenQR() {
    $('#qrview').css('background', ''); 
    if (QRtarget == 1){
        $('#qrview').css('background', 'url(<?php require('api/getqr.php?t=1') ?>) no-repeat center center');
    } else if (QRtarget == 2){
        $('#qrview').css('background', 'url(<?php require('api/getqr.php?t=2') ?>) no-repeat center center');       
    }
    $('#qrview').css('background-size', '100%');
}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function loginForm(){
    document.getElementById('dialog-label').innerHTML = 'Login here';
    $('#div-dialog-body').css('max-height', '270px');
    $('#dialog-content').html('<div id="form-container"><form id="login-form"><label for="username">Username/Email :</label><br><input id="username" style="width: 220px;margin-left:25px"/><br><br><label for="password">Password :</label><br><input id="password" type="password" style="width: 220px;margin-left:25px;"/><br><br><a href="#" style="color:blue;float:right;">Not registered? Click to sign up.</a></form></div><br><div id="btn-login" onclick="submitLogin()">Submit</div>');  
}
function submitLogin(){
    var username = document.getElementById('username').value;
    var password = document.getElementById('password').value;

    if (username.length == 0) {
        alert('Please enter a username');
        return false;
    }
    if (username.length < 8) {
        alert('Username should be at least 8 characters long.');
        return false;
    }
    if (password.length == 0) {
        alert('Please enter a password');
        return false;
    }
    if (password.length < 6) {
        alert('Password should be at least 6 characters long.');
        return false;
    }   
    var usernameType;
    if (ValidateEmail(username)){
        usernameType = 'email';
    } else {
        if (ValidatePhone(username)){
            usernameType = 'phone';
        } else {
            if (ValidateUsername(username)){
                usernameType = 'username';
            } else {
                alert('Invalid username! Please enter a valid e-mail address, phone number or username.');
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    if (ValidatePassword(password)){
        return submit(usernameType, username, password);
    } else {
        alert('Invalid password! Please enter a valid password. Valid password is minimum 6 characters long and contains alphabets, digits and special characters e.g. \"@#$%!?\/*-_.|\"');
        return false;
    }   
}
function submit(usernameType, username, password){

}
function ValidateUsername(username){
    return true;
}
function ValidatePassword(password){
    return false;
}
function ValidatePhone(phone){
    return false;
}
function ValidateEmail(mail) {
 if (/^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/.test(mail)){
    return true;
  }
    return false;
}
function trackQR(){
    closeDialog();
    showDialog(5);
}
function connectQR(target){
    QRtarget = target;
    w3_close();
    showDialog(4);
}
</script>
<title>cart</title> 
</head>
<body>
<!-- Sidebar -->
<div class="w3-sidebar w3-bar-block" id="nav-menu" style="z-index:1006;">
  <button onclick="w3_close()" class="w3-bar-item w3-button" style="background-color:#430032;font-size:0.9em;">Close &times;</button>
  <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">My Account</a>
  <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">My cart</a>
  <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Track my order</a>
  <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Feedback & Dispute</a>
  <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Invite a Friend</a>
  <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">About</a> 
  <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Contact</a>   
</div>
<!-- -->
<!-- cart -->
<div class="w3-sidebar w3-bar-block" id="nav-cart" style="z-index:1006;">
  <button onclick="w3_close_cart()" class="w3-bar-item w3-button" style="background-color:#430032;font-size:0.9em;">Close &times;</button>
  <div style="width: 100%; height: 5%; background-color:red;font-size:0.7em;padding-left:40px;">My cart</div>
  <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">My Account</a>
  <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">My cart</a>
  <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Link 3</a>
</div>
<!------------>
<!-- dialog new -->
  <div id="div-dialog-cover">
  </div>
    <div id="div-dialog-back">
        <div id="div-dialog-close-back">
            <div id="dialog-close-btn">
                <span class="icon-cancel-circle" onclick="closeDialog()"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="div-dialog-body">
            <div id="dialog-label"></div>
            <div id="dialog-content" style="text-align:center">

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

<!------------>

<div id="header" class="header">

    <div id="h-top-p">
        <div id="h-top-menu" class="button" onclick="w3_open()">
            <div class="icons">
                <i class="icon-menu"></i>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="div-wallet">
            <div class="assets-main-div">
              <span id="wallet" class="icon-coin-dollar" style="font-size: 1.5em"></span>
              <div class="assets-vals-out">
                <div class="asset-val-div">
                  1300
                  <div class="asset-add-div">
                    +
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="div-orders-left">
            <div class="assets-main-div">
              <span id="price-tag" class="icon-price-tags"></span>
              <div class="assets-vals-out">
                <div class="asset-val-div">
                  100
                  <div class="asset-add-div">
                    +
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>      
    </div>
    <div id="h-middle">
        <div id="h-middle-logo">
            <img id="main-logo" src="res/imgs/title.png">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="h-bottom">
        <div id="w-button-container">
            <div id="w-button-1" class="w-button" onclick="showDialog(1)">
                <div class="w-icons">
                    <span id="w1" class="icon-target2"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="w-button-2" class="w-button">
                <div class="w-icons">
                    <span id="w2" class="icon-document-add"></span>
                </div>          
            </div>
            <div id="w-button-3" class="w-button">
                <div class="w-icons">
                    <span id="w3" class="icon-star-full"></span>
                </div>          
            </div>
            <div id="w-button-4" class="w-button" onclick="showDialog(4)">
                <div class="w-icons">
                    <span id="w4" class="icon-qrcode"></span>
                </div>          
            </div>
            <div id="w-button-5" class="w-button" onclick="showDialog(5)">
                <div class="w-icons">
                    <span id="w5" class="icon-camera"></span>
                </div>              
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="content-base" class="content-base">

</div>
<div id="footer" class="float-footer">
    <div class="footer-part">
        <span class="icon-bell"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="footer-part">
        <span class="icon-envelope"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="footer-part">
        <span class="icon-gift"></span>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="go-to-top" onclick="scroll2top()">
^
</div>
<a href="#" class="float" id="menu-share">
<i class="icon-chat-bubble-dots"></i>
</a>
<ul>
<li><a href="#">
<i class="icon-phone"></i>
</a></li>
<li><a href="#">
<i class="icon-bubbles3"></i>
</a></li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is the code you are having trouble with? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ? Please, provide a [mcve].

Comment: Can you provide a *precise* specification of what it is that you want to happen, including any and all rules, exceptions from those rules, corner cases, special cases, boundary cases, and edge cases? Can you provide sample inputs and outputs demonstrating what you expect to happen, both in normal cases, and in all the exceptions, corner cases, special cases, boundary cases, and edge cases? Please, also make sure to provide a [mcve].

Comment: "It is behaving strange" is not a precise enough error description for us to help you. *What* doesn't work? *How* doesn't it work? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ?

Comment: "This is happening after I added some javascript tags in the head of my html." – What is a "javascript tag"? I could not find a definition of that term anywhere in the HTML5 specification.

Comment: Sorry, I have added my code now. Chrome console gives no errors.

Comment: @JörgWMittag thanks for your response. I tried the minimal verifiable approach and I sort of came to the point that is causing the problem. When I remove the php lines from my document and change the extension back to .html the page works fine. Reinserting the php code lines and converting the page to .php results into blank page.

Comment: To check if my php code is faulty I changed it to simply <?php echo "hello"; ?> but the problem is still there

Answer (score 1):

The problem is arising because of JavaScript code between line 123-163. Ensure proper parenthesis and syntax.Hope this helps.

Comment: There is some php code in these lines when I remove this php code and change the file extension back to .html the page works fine, inserting php code and changing the file extension to .php causes blank page in chrome.

Comment: @ZaeemAdil PHP is server-side technology. You need to use a PHP server. The PHP server will produce valid HTML after processing the page.